# Exclusive checkbox in QListView

Tags: c++, qt, qlistview

I'm trying to do exclusive checkboxes as a `QListView` items. I'm using `QStandardItemModel` as a model with `QStandardItem`'s.

I'm adding items to the list dynamically and set it checkable:

```
QStandardItem *item = new QStandardItem(treeView->model()->data(index).toString());
item->setCheckable(true);
m_categoriesModel->appendRow(item);
```

I tried connect all items to `QSignalMapper` but `QStandardItem` doesn't have `checked(bool)` signal (basically it does not have any).

Is there any way to solve the problem?

Comment: Why are you doing this? Why not just use the model that is attached to the treeView? This seems you're fighting against the whole point of the MVC pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always make it in the way described below. Firstly connect the clicked signal of ListView to the slot which will handle your items click. Secondly inside of the slot you can get the item from QModelIndex and check the state of the item. Below is pseudo code:

For example, in constructor of ListView:

```
  connect(this, SIGNAL(clicked(QModelIndex)), this, SLOT(_handleItemClicked(QModelIndex)));
```

Slot of ListView:

```
void ListView::_handleItemClicked(QModelIndex index)
{
        QStandardItem* item = _model->itemFromIndex(index);

        if( item->checkState() == Qt::Checked) qDebug() << "Checked!";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There actually is a class for exactly doing this: [`QButtonGroup`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qbuttongroup.html)

It's easy to use:

```
QButtonGroup *group = new QButtonGroup(this);
group->setExclusive(true);//now only one will be checked at a time
//add all buttons
group->addButton(this->ui->myFirstCheckbox);
//...
```

... at least for manually added buttons. Of course you can use it for the model too, but it would require you to find all the checkbox elements inside the view...

Comment: Unfortunately `QStandardItem` doesn't inherit `QAbstractButton` so I cannot use this solution.